# Wordpress, build a template for a post

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

I would like to know how can I define a post template and adding automatically the html layout when we are creating a post?

Do I have to use custom fields?

For example:

Post content:

```
   Title
    Description 1
    Description 2
    With links and social media
```

Html layout result:

```
   <h1 class="work-title">Title</h1>
       <div class="description">Description 1</div>
       <div class="description">Description 2</div>
       <div class="details">With links and social media</div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it always in the format above? First line is Title, second and third are descriptions, and last is details?

Comment: When I'm adding a simple post, this is the html result:

<p>title</p>
<p>description 1</p>
<p>description 2</p>
<p>social</p>
<p>see what is it here</p>

But I would like to know if I have to replace these tags by using Jquerry function or if there is a better way/ a feature/ a plugin that allow me to do it in the wordpress dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alter the output of the function `the_content()` by using (in `functions.php`) something like:

```
function alter_content($content) {
    // Alter the $content variable here
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'alter_content', 6);
```

Which will alter the content before the paragraphs are added. And if you don't want paragraphs at all use:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Check out [the codex page on apply_filters()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) for more info on the function.